# Can the Raspberry Pi cluster be used with Unreal Engine 4 to split up tasks and make it faster?

Tags: cluster

I am planning on building a raspberry pi cluster with my computer so can it be used to run UE4 faster and more efficiently on my computer than without the raspberry pi cluster(4 raspberry pi’s)?

Comment: Pi clusters aren't worthwhile in terms of cost vs. performance.  The *are* worthwhile cost wise in terms of learning about clustering.  Put another way, if you add up the cost of a pi cluster, whatever it is doing could be done faster with different hardware at the same cost.  If that's a 4 pi cluster, the "different hardware" could be, eg., a vector graphics card.  However, you won't learn about clustering that way.  If your goal is to "run UE4 faster", a pi cluster is probably the most awkward and cost ineffective way to do it.  An interesting novelty.

Comment: But lets take building the lighting in the scene as an example. Wouldn’t it be more efficient for all the processes to be split up among 4 cpus?

Comment: Not anywhere remotely close to doing it on a PCI-E connected GPU (if plausible; I would assume UE makes some probably substantial use of graphics hardware), or spending the $200-300 on a bigger faster CPU for whatever other machine is supposed to be participating in this.  Keep in mind the data transfer speed between nodes in the cluster and the cluster and whatever else is going to be way, way, way, way too slow to involve generating intensive 3D graphics in real time.  Also keep in mind that ARM chips are pound for pound worse performance wise than X86-64 processors...

Comment: Ie., a 1.5 Ghz ARM64 chip is not as good as a 1.5 Ghz x64 chip. Of source, if the scenario is that you can't use a GPU card or get a faster processor, 4 Pi 4s could have more processing power than a prebuilt system that cost $2-300 (or I guess $4-500 depending on the Pi RAM).  The main point I'm trying to make is that if you want to try making a pi cluster to see what it can do, great, and have fun.  But if what you want to accomplish is adding muscle to a graphics engine, you are going to be wasting your money and end up disappointed.